# How would an immortal go about conquering the world?

Tags: warfare, humans, immortality

Bob Jennings is immortal. His abilities are such:

- He is completely immune to bodily harm, i.e. bullets bounce off of him, he can't get killed by anything.
- He does not have to breathe or eat.
- He is immune to all diseases.
- He does not age.

There is no way to kill him, i.e. he will necessarily live forever unless he chooses to die (irrelevant how that happens).

He also has super strength. He is approx. 2-3x stronger than the average human, meaning that he can beat almost anyone in a fistfight, but can still be restrained by a pair of handcuffs.

He has one goal:

**Take over the world!**

There are a few restrictions on how he will do this:

- Maximum 15% of total human life killed during his conquest since he still wants a large population to rule over.
- The internet and communications infrastructure must remain intact, in case he wants to while away the hours looking at cat gifs on Facebook.

**BONUS POINTS if he...**

- Can pull off his plan within 15-20 years. Although time is meaningless to him, he wants to ascend as soon as possible (those cat gifs won't watch themselves!).
- He wants society to be pretty much the same as before (i.e. not a communist totalitarian dictatorship like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four). He wants the general population to be fairly content, although rebels and the like must obviously perish.
- The amount of fighting should be minimized as much as possible.

**If it is impossible to conquer the world so quickly, then an explanation of why not will suffice!**

## Thanks and have a good day!

(NOTE: I probably screwed up on the tags, if you have any suggestions, let me know!)

Comment: It looks like you're asking about the actions and decisions about an individual that exists within your world rather than about building the world itself. Such questions aren't a good fit for this site.

Comment: @sphennings   https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/94154/how-to-safely-check-if-you-are-immortal This one is about the actions of one person

Comment: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12348/how-do-you-prove-youre-from-the-future So is this one... In fact, most questions are about (what would my guy do if he wants to do x) I could bring many more examples if I wanted to...

Comment: I respectfully disagree with the closing. According to our rules [Why is my question "Too Story Based" and how do I get it opened?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3300/49) the questions like "What would?" are generally off-topic, while the questions like "How would?" are on-topic. This question is clearly latter rather than former.

Comment: This time limit is about a mortal level. It is too few. I think he should build up political and economical influence from the background. If he has infinite time, he can collect infinite skill to grab and manage the power. Obviously he must remain hidden.

Answer (score 6):

1. Found the Church of Bob Jennings
2. Write the new scriptures, asserting the need of establishing the heavenly kingdom of Bob Jennings on Earth.
3. Assemble the followers, impress everyone with miracles.
4. Wait until the Church of Bob Jennings come to power in most of the countries.
5. Complete the power grab by redrawing the world map.

Answer (score 2):

- Get your DNA sequenced and patent the findings.
- From that DNA, extract the secrets of immortality, all-disease-immunity, freedom from asphyxiation, starvation, thirst and harm, along with super-strength.
- Sell those secrets to the mortal, sick and frail people in return for their eternal (but harmless) subjugation.
- Order your new immortal/indestructible army to kill everyone who didn't go for your offer.

Enjoy your cat videos.

Comment: Why would the indestructible armies follow my lead? Why can't they rebel?

Comment: You have eliminated hunger, illness and death and all you want in return is cat videos.  Why would anyone rebel?

Answer (score 2):

#### Dividend reinvestment

1. Get a part time job doing whatever you can.
2. Invest as much as your earnings as possible in shares / bonds / high interest (if that ever comes back)

   - immortals don't need shelter or food so can have minimal expenses.
3. Study part time in any course they'll let you do.
4. When course is finished, see if you can get a better job with that training.
5. Start another part time course at a higher level.
6. Repeat indefinitely.

As you save money, you'll be able to invest more. Investment is taxed lower than labour in most  countries, so pretty soon you're money will be earning you pretty good returns. As you get more training you'll be able to earn more with labour too.

Your shares will pay dividends, use those dividends to buy more shares and grow your net worth. Within about 200 years you can go from minimum wage to trillionaire, and become part of the top-100 rich list. Once you're this rich you can just sponsor politicians like Nascar drivers.